# How to make a custom video player W/ embed options! Rare

Tags: java, wordpress, actionscript-3

**First question:**  What would be the best language to create a video player in? / Anyone point me in the direction of a tut that can help me write said script?

**Second Question:** How can I code such player to echo a embed code for each video: Ala youtube/break/viemo.

^ whats amazing to me, is the fact I searched google for a day and a half and haven't even come close to someone explaining how to build a video player, let alone have a option for it to spit out a embed code or any other sharing options.

**Usage info:**  Once the player is finished it will be imported into wordpress, so I can have total control of each video and manage them accordingly.  Not asking for help for importing to WP but any tips would be great.

{Please don't point me to VideoJS or any other video service, as I will make my own and not pay for a license.}

Comment: Away this post goes into the depths of non-votes on SO.

Comment: Can you really blame people for not voting?  You ask two questions in one question, and both are general descriptions of a product, instead of a problem that can be solved.  In general, a video player only need thirty pictures to display per second, and time the launch of an audio stream that is synchronized with the pictures.  In practice, how you do that is as limited as the number of stars in the sky, or perhaps even bigger than that when adding in "features" which aren't even clearly described.

Answer (score 3):

In general, a video player is a picture gallery, where twenty four (or more) pictures are displayed in order every second during the entire duration of the film.  Twenty four is the lowest limit for a person to visually confuse static pictures with motion, for better effects I would recommend thirty or more.

The second component of a video player is typically a music player, which displays many "frames" of music per second, which blend through the digital to analog playback system into something resembling continuous sound.

Getting these two subsystems to operate without letting one get ahead of the other is generally required for a "video playback" system.  There are many "already done" systems, but it sounds like you envision building your own (to add in unique "features").

Keep in mind that there are very large volumes of data moving around in "video playback".  This means that if it is possible, compressing the data is vital for reasonable performance.  Compression routines are not as simple as they seem, and the major video codecs are those that do a good job of balancing CPU cycles to decompress, file size, and resulting image quality.

Assuming you really don't want to write a video player, but just want to use someone else's video player "with enhancements", you will be at the mercy of how well built the existing video player is, whether or not it supports any kind of customization, and if it does, how well it supports the customization you have in mind.

Since speed is such a consideration, even though more advanced languages exist, traditionally these things are done in C, assembly, or even hardware acceleration chips.

Comment: In the main question he want to target Wordpress, so I suppose there is no clear message when you talk about 'C, assembly, or even hardware acceleration chips' :)

Comment: @www.creative-geeks.com Odds are you are right, I probably shot a bit over what was needed, but I did hit what was asked.  Custom video player has many meanings, and I'm pretty sure that _this_ meaning wasn't the one requested, even though it was, well, _requested_.

Comment: @Edmin Buck, also true! Although the main question is more a multidimensional question, and quite unclear, your explanation sure is interesting and relevant side information!

Answer (score 1):

These are my thought, although you should try to search a little better... Tutorials are very easy to find ...

You could use Flash / ActionScript to create a custom video player. It's still common on the net, although more and more non-flash players are rising (HTML5). I still prefer Flash  because of the performance, but keep in mind that iPhone / iPad doesn't support Flash...

If you are going to script your own videoplayer in Flash, [this](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/build-a-dynamic-video-player-with-actionscript-3-part-1-of-3/) tutorial will set you off to create your own implementation...

For your second question:
Just create a database with a unique ID for every video URL your player will have. When you create the embed code you can include this unique ID as a URL var to the main video player.
From there on you can call your player page with URL vars (example: http://www.yourlink.com?videoid=ID).

When you embed your SWF object you can then pass the videoid along with a `FlashVar`, or prefetch the matching video URL and send that URL with a `FlashVar` to your SWF. It's not so complicated, more info can be found [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html).

Answer (score 0):

try [osmf.org](http://osmf.org). You can either use the strobe media playback with it or build your own player around it. OSMF is pretty robust